# DB2- SQL - Group and move the data in each row to different columns in various tables

Tags: sql, db2, logic, db2-luw

I'm looking for best solution for my below scenario in DB2.
I have data present in a single column table and  i want to separate the data in each row to individual columns.

My input table:

```html
Data
A012356TEST12501 
M012385749635201 
N012385749635201 
B012356TEST12501    
A022356TEST12501 
M022385749635201 
N022385749635201 
B022356TEST12501
```

I want to move the data in the above table to multiple tables. i.e the data in the table will be moved to 4 different tables. For each of the table, i have the detail of the column length to sub string.

```html
Table_A
col1 col2 col3  col4  col5 
A    01   2356  TEST  12501
A    02   2356  TEST  12501
Table_M
col1 col2 col3  col4  col5 
M    012  3857  49635  201
M    022  2385  74963  201
```

Similarly, Table _N and Table_B.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice, in that case; you have to use SUBSTR(), a pretty CPU intensive string function, if run on lots of data:

```
WITH
-- your input, in a WITH CLAUSE
data_t(data_s) AS (
          SELECT 'A012356TEST12501' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'M012385749635201' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N012385749635201' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'B012356TEST12501' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1   
UNION ALL SELECT 'A022356TEST12501' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'M022385749635201' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'N022385749635201' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 'B022356TEST12501' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
)
SELECT
  SUBSTR(data_s, 1,1) AS col1
, SUBSTR(data_s, 2,2) AS col2
, SUBSTR(data_s, 4,4) AS col3
, SUBSTR(data_s, 8,5) AS col4
, SUBSTR(data_s,13,3) AS col5
FROM data_t;
-- out  col1 | col2 | col3 | col4  | col5 
-- out ------+------+------+-------+------
-- out  A    | 01   | 2356 | TEST1 | 250
-- out  M    | 01   | 2385 | 74963 | 520
-- out  N    | 01   | 2385 | 74963 | 520
-- out  B    | 01   | 2356 | TEST1 | 250
-- out  A    | 02   | 2356 | TEST1 | 250
-- out  M    | 02   | 2385 | 74963 | 520
-- out  N    | 02   | 2385 | 74963 | 520
-- out  B    | 02   | 2356 | TEST1 | 250
```

But if you get that data from an ASCII file, you could also:

```
CREATE TABLE splitup (
  col1 CHAR(1)
, col2 SMALLINT
, col3 SMALLINT
, col4 CHAR(5)
, col5 SMALLINT
); 

LOAD FROM your_in_file OF ASC MODIFIED BY STRIPTBLANKS RECLEN=16
METHOD L (
  1  1
, 2  3
, 4  7
, 8 12
,13 16
)
INSERT INTO TABLE (
  col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
, col5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your four tables have the same number of columns, and of the same data type, you could consider an `INSERT` into a `UNION ALL` `VIEW` of the four (row organized) tables that are each constrained on COL1.

However, that is probably not the case (e.g. Col4 in your example looks like a CHAR in table A and an a INTEGER or DECIMAL in table B).

The simple solution is just 4 `INSERT` statements, with a SUBSTR for each column, and a `WHERE SUBSTR(Date,1,1) = 'A'` , `= 'N'` etc for each target table